# Hotswap failed intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, hotswap

An error happens when updating classes and resources while in a debug session in Intellij.

Hotswap failed: [whatever] reason.

This error is produced when Intellij's Hotswap fails and the code in question is not updated by debugger.

How to solve this ? so that I don't have to stop and start the debug process again.

Answer (score 2):

From what I've figured out this usually fails if the debugger is paused at some break point in the code. If you resume the program and try to update classes and resources it should work fine.